# Dataview Webpart

Tags: data-view-web-part

I have a page where I am using dataview webpart that has 2 diferent list as datasource ... I am working on the page in Sharepoing Designer 2007 and see that it does work good. But when I try to see it in browser, it gives below error -

> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For
>   more information, contact your site administrator. Troubleshoot issues
>   with Windows SharePoint Services.

0
    
        Table

Below is the code in my page:

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" PartImageSmall="" DataSourceID="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." ListName="Autorizacion SAO" FrameType="Default" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" DetailLink="/SCMPlanificacion/VP00/Autorizacion SAO/Forms/DVWP.aspx" ExportControlledProperties="True" IsVisible="True" AllowRemove="True" AllowEdit="True" ID="g_498a8b5c_487b_4b0a_9c43_b8a6ce201d2d" Dir="Default" FrameState="Normal" DisplayName="DVWP" ViewContentTypeId="0x" AllowConnect="True" PageSize="100" Default="TRUE" AllowMinimize="True" IsIncludedFilter="" TitleUrl="/SCMPlanificacion/VP001245/Autorizacion SAO/Forms/DVWP.aspx" ShowWithSampleData="False" HelpMode="Modeless" ExportMode="All" ViewFlag="1" Title="Autorizacion SAO" HelpLink="" AllowHide="True" AllowZoneChange="True" PartOrder="1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" PartImageLarge="" IsIncluded="True" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{498A8B5C-487B-4B0A-9C43-B8A6CE201D2D}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
    <DataSources>
        <SharePoint:AggregateDataSource runat="server" IsSynchronous="" SeparateRoot="true" RootName="" RowsName="">
            <Sources>
                <SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query/&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" UseInternalName="True" IncludeHidden="True">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Autorizacion SAO" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="RootFolder" Name="RootFolder" Type="String"></asp:QueryStringParameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="StartRowIndex"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="nextpagedata"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="100" Name="MaximumRows"></asp:Parameter>
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Autorizacion SAO" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                    </UpdateParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Autorizacion SAO" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Autorizacion SAO" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                    </DeleteParameters>
                </SharePoint:SPDataSource>
                <SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" UseInternalName="True">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Tasks" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Tasks" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                    </UpdateParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Tasks" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Tasks" Name="ListName"></asp:Parameter>
                    </DeleteParameters>
                </SharePoint:SPDataSource>
            </Sources>
            <Aggregate>
                <concat name="data source">
                    <datasource name="Autorizacion_SAO" id="0" Type="SPList" />
                    <datasource name="Tasks" id="1" Type="SPList" />
                </concat>
            </Aggregate>
        </SharePoint:AggregateDataSource>
    </DataSources>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I suggested that Perla post over here when s/he asked a question on my blog. Obviously, some context and a specific question would be helpful, Perla.

Comment: Hi Lucas and Mark the problem is this im trying to re-use one dataview webpart in a diferent site but it doesnt work good :'( i need help pls

Comment: Hi Lucas and Mark the problem is this im trying to re-use one dataview webpart in a diferent site but it doesnt work good :'( i need help pls

Comment: You haven't included many details in your question?

Comment: You seem to have asked the same, or very similar, question twice. Merging these two questions.

Comment: You still haven't shown enough of your code to help. All you have above is the DVWP header. I think that your problem is either in the DataSource section or the XSL.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson: The `DataSource` section was there, but obfuscated by the formatting. It'll be fixed once my edit is approved.

Comment: Thanks, Stuart. I was looking on my iPhone at the time and could only see the top section.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a Dataview Webpart of one site in another site, It will not work as it refers sites and lists by GUIDs which will change even if their name are same.

Try to update the GUIDs as well.

Comment: As you can see in the posted code, Perla has switched from ListID to ListName. This helps to make the DVWP more portable from site to site.

Comment: hi Mark i found the error ... :( but i istill without to know how to resolve it ... My list Autorizacion SAO and Tasks are linked by a field called @WorkflowLink then but i dont know how can i chanced this Value field for the new one ... is like embebed field or internal field coz i dont know where can i change this value :S I hope so someone cans help me pls

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong. I'd check to make sure that the list names are exactly the same in the two sites.

The only other thing that I see that looks a little odd is that the selectcommand for the Autorizacion SAO list has a <Query/> in it which isn't needed.

Finally, the error you are getting isn't normally the one you would get if you have an error in a DVWP. It usually indicates a different type of issue, so check that you haven't inadvertently inserted or removed something else when you added the DVWP to the page.

Comment: hi Mark i found the error ... :( but i istill without to know how to resolve it ... My list Autorizacion SAO and Tasks are linked by a field called @WorkflowLink then but i dont know how can i chanced this Value field for the new one ... is like embebed field or internal field coz i dont know where can i change this value :S I hope so someone cans help me pls

Comment: my webpart is trying to use the same value from first site in new one site (@WorkflowLink) HELP MEE PLS :'(

Comment: That sounds like an issue with how you created the lists, not anything to do with the DVWP itself, as I suspected. The DVWP will want the lists to have the same structures and be related in the same way as in your original site.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, the XSLt for that webpart is somewhere wrong! Check in log files, is there any lines related this error. That'll help you solve the issue easily.

Comment: hi Shantha I found the error ... :( but i istill without to know how to resolve it ... My list Autorizacion SAO and Tasks are linked by a field called @WorkflowLink then but i dont know how can i chanced this Value field for the new one ... is like embebed field or internal field coz i dont know where can i change this value :S I hope so someone cans help me pls