# dataview webpart from two lists

Tags: data-view-web-part

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dataview Webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24027/dataview-webpart)

in need help :( pls

**i have this page where im using dataview webparts that has as source 2 diferent list ... im watinching the page at Sharepoing Designer 2007 and see that it does work good. but when i trying to see it at Browse mode send me one error like this ...
An unexpected error has occurred.**

Web Parts Maintenance Page: If you have permission, you can use this page to temporarily close Web Parts or remove personal settings. For more information, contact your site administrator.
Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

here ...a part of my page code 

        
        






    


    


    


    


    


    


    


    



 ----

Best regards